# Is the use of "function $var() { }" true in php?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and in controller folder, I created a php file like :
**NOTE:** connects database automaticly.

```
<?php

    class Book extends CI_Controller {

        $query = $this->db->get('books');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

            function $row->book_name() {
                echo $row->book_name;
            }

        }

    }

?>
```

I tried to create functions by fetching book names from the database but I can not. By using $variable in function name, is it possible to create function? If not, How can create it in a quick way? Thanks...

Comment: One does not simply start writing logic directly under a class. Your logic **has** to go inside a function.

Comment: For people wondering what this is asking: if the database contains the books `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, the OP wants to generate member functions named `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, each of which return something.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.

```
$myfunction = function($a,$b,$c) {return $a+$b+$c;};
```

This is an example of an anonymous function. It has no name, but it can be accessed by `$myfunction(1,2,3)`.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do in your example... Should just `echo $row->book_name` alone be enough? Or are you trying to define a function with the same name as a book? In the latter case, you can use variable variables: `${$row->book_name} = function...` - it's probably not a good idea though.

Comment: Side-note: functions defined like this were added in PHP 5.3. If you're (still) using an older version, use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/create-function) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be interested in [__call()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

If a call is made to a method in a class that does not exist, the `__call()` method is invoked and you can handle the call from there.

Store the books in an array as you read the results, and add a `__call` method to your class.  When the method is accessed, you can search the array for the book based on the name of the function called and act appropriately.

```
class Book extends CI_Controller {
    protected $_books = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $query = $this->db->get('books');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $this->_books[] = $row->book_name;
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if (in_array($name, $this->_books)) {
            echo $name;
        } else {
            ehco 'I do not have this book!';
        }
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind PHP's rules for naming methods, a valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.  No spaces are allowed so keep that in mind.

Comment: This is the only answer to what the question is really asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is it [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) that you are searching for?

But seriously, it took me a minute to google it..

Comment: PHP now has support for proper anonymous functions, and even closures.